# Test class data creation - Salesforce Files

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am needing to create test data within my test class to simulate adding a content document link row. I have a trigger on the ContentDocumentLink object, so just need to fire it. The Content Document Link Object has very few fields, so essentially has the LinkedEntityID and the ContentDocumentID.I have managed to create the test data on the LinkedEntityID side with associated related objects but am having trouble creating and accessing the Content Document ID. I thought creating a Content Version record would automatically create an associated Content Document record (and ID) but the value is coming back as null. If I try to create a Content Document manually the system says that DML operations are not allowed on the Content Document object.

Any assistance would be appreciated - thanks!

```
@isTest 
public class ELOTestclass {

    static testMethod void insertNewData() {

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new ELOHttpCalloutMock());

        Test.startTest();

        //Instantiate the test objects needed
        Account testAccount = new Account();
        Estate__c testEstate = new Estate__c();
        //Letter_Tracker__c testLetTrack = new Letter_Tracker__c();
        //Inventory__c testInv = new Inventory__c();
        ContentDocument testContDoc = new ContentDocument();
        ContentVersion testContVer = new ContentVersion();
        ContentDocumentLink testContDocLink = new ContentDocumentLink(); 

        //Populate and create the test Account
        testAccount.FirstName = 'Jean';
        testAccount.MiddleName = 'Claude';
        testAccount.LastName = 'Damme';
        testAccount.RecordTypeId = '01290000000AE6eAAG';
        insert testAccount; 

        //Populate and create the test Estate
        testEstate.Name = 'Test Estate 1';
        testEstate.Related_Person_Account__c = testAccount.Id;
        insert testEstate; 

        //Populate and create ContentVersion
        testContVer.Title = 'Test Document 2';
        testContVer.PathOnClient = 'SF_ELO_Code.txt';
        testContVer.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content');   
        testContVer.IsMajorVersion = true;
        insert testContVer;

        System.debug('testContVer = ' + testContVer);

        //Populate and create ContentDocumentLink
        testContDocLink.LinkedEntityId = testEstate.Id;
        testContDocLink.ContentDocumentId = testContVer.ContentDocumentId;
        insert testContDocLink;

        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

        // Verify response received contains fake values
        String contentType = res.getHeader('Content-Type');
        System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
        String actualValue = res.getBody();
        String expectedValue = '{"example":"test"}';
        System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
        System.assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode());

        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track: you just need to re-query your `ContentVersion` to get its populated `ContentDocumentId` field. Remember that only the Id is automatically populated in in-memory sObjects by an insert DML operation, even though in the background a parent record is being created for you.

Once you query that record, you'll in fact have the Id of that auto-created `ContentDocument` and can insert the link.

Comment: Thank you David!